# Convert current time to milliseconds using moment

Tags: javascript, momentjs

Suppose I have this time

```
'2018-08-03T15:53:57.000Z'
```

I need to convert only the time part to `milliseconds`

I tried this but didn't work and throws error

```
moment.utc("2018-08-03T15:53:57.000Z").format('HH:mm:ss').milliseconds()
```

**Error**

```
TypeError: (0 , _moment2.default)(...).format(...).milliseconds is not a function
```

Can someone please help how can I convert only time to millisecond?

Thank you!!!

Comment: What error does it throw?

Comment: @WilliamChong Updated the question

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Would you like milliseconds from 00:00 local user time to 15:53:57.000 UTC or 00:00 to 15:53:57.000 local user time?

Comment: new Date("2018-08-03T15:53:57.000Z").getTime()

Comment: @HMR From `00:00 to 15:53:57.000 local user time`

Comment: @MukeshVerma It gives me the millisecond of with the date part as well. I need only with the time

Comment: So the `Z` in `15:53:57.000Z` is not used at all? If you do `new Date('2018-08-03T15:53:57.000Z')` you'll likely get a different time unless you happen to be in the UK.

Comment: @HMR  Doesn't matter I need only the millisecond from the date. The answer should be `57237000`

Comment: The date string you provided shows Zulu time (is same as UTC) the time of day is only the time of day of people in the UK. If you live anywhere else the time will be different. For example: `new Date().toISOString()` will show a different time than the current time if you're not in the UK. So your expected output will be correct depending on what you define as 00:00 (00:00 in England or at the user's location)

Comment: Ok @HMR I got you. Now suppose I don't convert it to `UTC`. I want to extract milliseconds from it for the time only. So Could you please tell me how?

Comment: @HMR Just to clarify '2018-08-03T15:53:57.000Z' is actually '2018-08-03T16:53:57.000' local as we observe daylight savings between March and October ;)

Comment: What about days where daylight savings begins or ends? Do you want to include the offset or ignore it?

Comment: @phuzi Input is in Zulu (=UTC) time and does not observe DST so input cannot be ambiguous nor can midnight local time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No need to use moment to do this. The date string can be parsed sufficiently by vanilla JS.

```
let date = new Date('2018-08-03T15:53:57.000Z');
```

And to get the timestamp (in milliseconds) of this date;

```
let millis = date.getTime();
```

And, since there are 86400 seconds in a day (24*60*60) there are 86,400,000 milliseconds and we can use the remainder after division by this number to get the number of milliseconds the time portion represents. Following is the statement:

```
let millisToday = millis % 86400000;
```

**UPDATE**

Now using `getTime()` instead of `valueOf()` as it is the "proper" way to get the timestamp of the Date object.

Comment: I'd recommend using [getTime](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/getTime) instead.

Comment: @HMR Would like to elaborate as to why? How is it different to `valueOf()`?

Comment: getTime was explicitly created to get milliseconds after epoch where valueOf is a general function used in type coercion.

Comment: For more info; here is an example of type coercion: `1 - {valueOf:()=>1}` is 0 where `1 - {valueOf:()=>2}` is -1

Answer (score 6):

Simply do this if you want to get the milliseconds:

```
const ms = moment.utc("2018-08-03T15:53:57.000Z").valueOf()
```

Edit:
The above is how you could do it in moment since you specifically said "using Moment".

You could also use plain JS without using a library as follows:

```
const date = new Date("2018-08-03T15:53:57.000Z");
```

**`.valueOf()`**

```
date.valueOf() // 1533311637000
```

**`.getTime()`**

```
date.getTime() // 1533311637000
```

Answer (score 1):

I'll add my answer in case I got it wrong then someone can comment.

If I send `new Date().toISOString()` to someone in a different time zone then the time will differ for this person. If I ask that person to have a skype call at 13:00 their time it could mean it's 18:00 my local time.

So if the person sending me the date string is from the UK and sends me `...T13:00.000Z` That actually means 18:00 for me.

Here is how you can correctly get the time in milliseconds from your midnight of the date converted to your local time:

```js
const date = new Date(2007, 1, 1, 0, 0, 2).toISOString();
console.log('date:',date);
console.log('date in your local time:',new Date(date).toString());
const millisecondsFromMidNight = (date) => {
  var dateObject = new Date(date);
  return (
    dateObject.getTime() -
    new Date(
      dateObject.getFullYear(),
      dateObject.getMonth(),
      dateObject.getDate(),
      0,
      0,
      0,
      0,
    ).getTime()
  );
};
console.log(millisecondsFromMidNight(date));
```

Example where DST goes in effect:

```js
var minutesFromMidnight = (date) => {
  var dateObject = new Date(date);
  console.log('date:', date);
  console.log(
    'date in your local time:',
    dateObject.toString(),
  );
  return (
    dateObject.getTime() -
    new Date(
      dateObject.getFullYear(),
      dateObject.getMonth(),
      dateObject.getDate(),
      0,
      0,
      0,
      0,
    ).getTime()
  );
};

console.log(
  minutesFromMidnight('2018-10-28T00:59:00.000Z') / 60000,
);
console.log(
  minutesFromMidnight('2018-10-28T01:01:00.000Z') / 60000,
);
```

Comment: This will likely fail if there is a change in daylight savings on the date in question. e.g. in the UK, on 25 March 2018 at 01:00 daylight savings began so the time is then `2018-03-25T02:00:00+01:00` but midnight was `2018-03-25T00:00:00+00:00`. Although it is only one hour since midnight, i believe your answer will count 2. Don't know if that's a level of detail beyond what OP wants though!

Comment: @phuzi I have added an example minutes from midnight with one value in DST and one 2 minutes later out of DST (western Europe) and it works correctly.

Comment: @HMR Thank you for the help but I think phuzi's answer is correct

Comment: @Profer It is if you're in the UK and not currently in DST.

Comment: What  DST refers to?

Comment: @Profer Daylight savings time, the date string you have is Zulu time so if `new Date().toISOString()` does not have the time where you currently are or you're in DST then it won't work correctly.

Comment: @Profer [getTime](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/getTime#Return_value) or [valueOf](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/valueOf#Description) will give you milliseconds after `1 January 1970 00:00:00 UTC` so if you're not in UTC (=Zulu) or in DST period it will give the wrong result.

Comment: @Profer Yes but UTC does not observe DST so it only works in winter.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/184136/discussion-between-hmr-and-profer).

Answer (score -1):

The function is moment().milliseconds()

Not format().milliseconds